# Cassandra data directory does not get updated with deletion

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking

Currently, I am bench marking Cassandra database using YCSB framework. During this time I have performed (batch) insertion and deletion of the data quite regularly. 
I am using **Truncate** command to delete keyspace rows. However, I am noticing that my Cassandra data directory swells up as the experiments.

I have checked and can confirm that even there is no data in the keystore when I checked the size of data directory. Is there a way to initialize a process so that Cassandra automatically release the stored space, or does it happen over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Truncate` cassandra will create snapshots of your data.

To disable it you will have to set `auto_snapshot: false` in cassandra.yaml file.

If you are using `Delete`, then cassandra use tombstone,i.e your data will not get deleted immediately. Data will get deleted once compaction is ran.

To remove previous snapshots one can use `nodetool snapshot` command.

Comment: Data is physically deleted when compaction is ran AND only after GCGraceSeconds since tombstone mark (logical delete). More details here https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes